# should I fill in the Background verification before accepting the offer letter?

Tags: background-check

I recently got a job offer from a big MNC. They sent me the offer letter through mail and asked me to fill in the verification form (offered by third party services like HireRight).

Now I don't have an idea that my manager will relive me or not (chances are that he might not). I have not accepted the offer letter for now. So is it OK to fill the background verification form or should I leave it?

Please help me out here as I don't want to hinder my career. 
Basically my question is that is it fine to fill in the verification form even if you don't accept the offer letter?

Comment: Every job offer I have ever received (in the US) has been contingent on the background check (and drug screen).  If you are not going to accept the offer, then it makes little sense to grant permission for the background check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are **certain** that you are going to take the position, it would be inadvisable to fill out the background check form. It likely asks for detailed personal information and without knowing the internal safeguards which may exist at the target company, you may be exposing yourself to identity theft.

If or when you are certain that you'll take the position and respond to the offer letter, then that would the time to fill out a form authorizing a background check. Until then, I would forego doing this.